# Docker-compose failing to run a jar file but works with Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have configure the next Dockerfile and it works fine:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
VOLUME /tmp
ADD farr-api-0.1.0.jar app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
```

Now I would like to run the same but using docker-compose, so I try to use the same sintaxys, this is my docker-compose.yml:

Docker-compose.yml:

```
jar:
  image: frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
  volumes:
    - /tmp
  add: "farr-api-0.1.0.jar" "app.jar"
  command: sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
  environment:
    JAVA_OPTS=""
  entrypoint: [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
```

It throws the next fail:

```
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 2, column 3
expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 5, column 29
```

I think it could be sintax problem

Docker-compose version 1.8.1

Comment: What version of docker-compose are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two syntax errors in your `docker-compose.yml` file:

- Docker-Compose does not support the `add` command. If you want to add a file to your container, you either have to do that in a `Dockerfile` (and use that from the compose file), or map in the file through a `volume`.

  ```
    volumes:
      - "./farr-api-0.1.0.jar:/app.jar"
  ```
- The `environment` section expects an array - you need to prefix the `JAVA_OPTS` line with a dash:

  ```
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=""
  ```

You can find more details in the [Docker-Compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file)

Comment: Really thanks, but how can I map the file through a volume?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to map in the file. I suggest you read through the Docker Compose documentation to see how these things are configured. All of your questions so far have answers and examples in the Docker Compose documentation.

Comment: It works really fine :) And I would go to read the documentation. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that! Make sure to bookmark that documentation page, it has lots of good examples!

Comment: Yes really thanks, I would try to read all the documentation for future problems I could have a better idea of all. Really thanks.